# How to stop threads from Firebase Java Admin SDK

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

By running the sample code of
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-java/blob/master/src/test/java/com/google/firebase/database/integration/ShutdownExample.java

```
public class ShutdownExample {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Semaphore shutdownLatch = new Semaphore(0);

FirebaseApp app =
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(
        new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setDatabaseUrl("https://admin-java-sdk.firebaseio.com")
            .build());

FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(app);
db.setLogLevel(Level.DEBUG);
DatabaseReference ref = db.getReference();

ValueEventListener listener =
    ref.child("shutdown")
        .addValueEventListener(
            new ValueEventListener() {
              @Override
              public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                Boolean shouldShutdown = snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
                if (shouldShutdown != null && shouldShutdown) {
                  System.out.println("Should shut down");
                  shutdownLatch.release(1);
                } else {
                  System.out.println("Not shutting down: " + shouldShutdown);
                }
              }

              @Override
              public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                System.err.println("Shouldn't happen");
              }
            });

try {
  // Keeps us running until we receive the notification to shut down
  shutdownLatch.acquire(1);
  ref.child("shutdown").removeEventListener(listener);
  db.goOffline();
  System.out.println("Done, should exit");
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
  throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

After calling `db.goOffline()`, there are still some threads running:

> Reference Handler Finalizer Signal Dispatcher FirebaseDatabaseWorker
>   pool-5-thread-1

How is it possible to clean it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going offline just means that the Firebase Realtime Database SDK will do no more networking.  It doesn't mean that its thread has to go away or that the program should exit.  If you're done with your work and want to exit the process, call `System.exit(0)`.

Comment: The call of System.exit(0) does the job.
But, if the thread runs in a Tomcat web server, System.exit(0) shuts down the whole Tomcat Web Server and also other web applications shut down.

Comment: What I'm recommending is for simple main() style execution of some Firebase database code.  For services that stay up indefinitely, don't do that.  Simply let the (Tomcat) container determine when to exit.  The Firebase thread will not prevent that from happening.